# ReactJS / Material UI : tick checkboxes for those that match

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an array that I want to pass to checkboxes and then from this list of checkboxes, tick those that match.

The user array:

```
[
    {
        "Category": "XXX",
        "Name": "123",
        "Weight": "1"
    },
    {
        "Category": "ZZZ",
        "Name": "456",
        "Weight": "2"
    }
]
```

Array of all:

```
[
    {
        "Category": "XXX",
        "Name": "123",
        "Weight": "1"
    },
    {
        "Category": "ZZZ",
        "Name": "456",
        "Weight": "2"
    },
    {
        "Category": "AAA",
        "Name": "789",
        "Weight": "2"
    },
    {
        "Category": "BBB",
        "Name": "012",
        "Weight": "2"
    }
]
```

So the result would look like this:

```
[X] 123 [X] 456 [ ]789 [ ]012
```

Basically, the user selects when adding to the collection items, and then when they update this collection, it needs to show them what they have already ticked, so they can add/remove from the array.

How can I achieve this? I am using Material UI Checkbox.

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[link code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-in-material-ui-b45qq)

```
    import "./styles.css";
import FormGroup from "@mui/material/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
const listAll = [
  {
    Category: "XXX",
    Name: "123",
    Weight: "1"
  },
  {
    Category: "ZZZ",
    Name: "456",
    Weight: "2"
  },
  {
    Category: "AAA",
    Name: "789",
    Weight: "2"
  },
  {
    Category: "BBB",
    Name: "012",
    Weight: "2"
  }
];
const listUser = [
  {
    Category: "XXX",
    Name: "123",
    Weight: "1"
  },
  {
    Category: "ZZZ",
    Name: "456",
    Weight: "2"
  }
];
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FormGroup>
        {listAll.map((t) => (
          <FormControlLabel
            control={
              <Checkbox checked={listUser.some((p) => p.Name === t.Name)} />
            }
            label={t.Name}
          />
        ))}
      </FormGroup>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: perfect for matching them, but it does not allow me to check the other text boxes and add them back into the User array?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-in-material-ui-b45qq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I refresh my code

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
const defaultOptions = [
  {
    "Category": "XXX",
    "Name": "123",
    "Weight": "1"
  },
  {
    "Category": "ZZZ",
    "Name": "456",
    "Weight": "2"
  },
  {
    "Category": "AAA",
    "Name": "789",
    "Weight": "2"
  },
  {
    "Category": "BBB",
    "Name": "012",
    "Weight": "2"
  }
];

/**
 * 
 * @param { selected }: selected = [
 *   {
 *       "Category": "XXX",
 *       "Name": "123",
 *       "Weight": "1"
 *   },
 *   {
 *       "Category": "ZZZ",
 *       "Name": "456",
 *       "Weight": "2"
 *   }
 * ]
 */
const CheckBoxes = ({ selected, onChange }) => {
  // update automatically according to "selected"
  const options = useMemo(() => defaultOptions.map(option => ({
    ...option,
    checked: selected.some(({ Name }) => Name === option.Name) // assume Name is unique
  })), [selected]);

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <FormLabel component="legend">{/* label */}</FormLabel>
      <FormGroup>
        {options.map(({ Name, checked }) => (
          <FormControlLabel
            key={Name}
            control={
              <Checkbox checked={checked} onChange={onChange} name={Name} />
            }
            label={Name}
          />
        ))}
      </FormGroup>
      <FormHelperText>Be careful</FormHelperText>
    </FormControl>
  )
};
```